# Number of possible 6-digit integers meeting three conditions

Tags: combinatorics

I have an integer ABCDEF.
How many different integers can I form if the below conditions must be met?

1. Digits A to F can take any value from 1 to 6.
2. None of the digits can occupy the position corresponding to its value (example of invalid integers: 123456, 134562, etc)
3. Digits cannot be repeated (example of invalid integer: 212345)

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried solving it by cases yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You are asking for a [Derangement](https://brilliant.org/wiki/derangements/) $D(6)$.

You can apply the [Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion](https://brilliant.org/wiki/principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-pie/#principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-generalized) to count this.